# Can't create a packet on scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I'm new to scapy.
I'm trying to combine scapy in a script, and not use it through bash. 
I'm intending to forge a packet.
By all the tutorials and .pdf's I saw, all explaining how to do it inside the scapy tool(in bash).

I tried the following code:

```
from scapy.all import *

a=IP()
a.src="10.0.0.30"
a.dst="10.0.0.138"
print a
```

I tried this just to get a print output like I would get in bash, that will look like:

```
<IP  src=10.0.0.20 dst=10.0.0.138|>
```

but insted I get unknown symbols, something like:

"EXX@f@

?"

My question is how do I get the same output that I got in bash??? I mean viewing the fields that I inserted.

Thanks for the responders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` statement in Python when used on a Scapy object will output the raw bytes of a packet.

You should use the `.show()` function for the packet you created to get the nice output you are expecting. Try the following in your python program.

```
a.show()
a.show2()
```

See this [Send and Receive](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) example in the Scapy docs for more.

A list of for examining the contents of the packet is also found [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#graphical-dumps-pdf-ps) - just scroll down to the "Command/Effect" table.